# How to protect my server from continous login attempts (Ubuntu)

Tags: authentication, server, ubuntu

This is the log of my server:

```
Mar 25 16:49:51 f4arelay sshd[10831]: input_userauth_request: invalid user git [preauth] 
Mar 25 16:49:51 f4arelay sshd[10831]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown 
Mar 25 16:49:51 f4arelay sshd[10831]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=115.29.194.97 
Mar 25 16:49:54 f4arelay sshd[10831]: Failed password for invalid user git from 115.29.194.97 port 43574 ssh2 
Mar 25 16:49:54 f4arelay sshd[10831]: Received disconnect from 115.29.194.97: 11: Bye Bye [preauth] 
Mar 25 16:50:08 f4arelay sshd[10473]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root 
Mar 25 16:52:49 f4arelay sshd[10841]: Invalid user vagrant from 115.29.194.97 
Mar 25 16:52:49 f4arelay sshd[10841]: input_userauth_request: invalid user vagrant [preauth] 
Mar 25 16:52:49 f4arelay sshd[10841]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown 
Mar 25 16:52:49 f4arelay sshd[10841]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=115.29.194.97 
Mar 25 16:52:51 f4arelay sshd[10841]: Failed password for invalid user vagrant from 115.29.194.97 port 35672 ssh2 
Mar 25 16:52:51 f4arelay sshd[10841]: Received disconnect from 115.29.194.97: 11: Bye Bye [preauth] 
Mar 25 16:55:45 f4arelay sshd[10845]: Invalid user vnc from 115.29.194.97 
Mar 25 16:55:45 f4arelay sshd[10845]: input_userauth_request: invalid user vnc [preauth] 
Mar 25 16:55:45 f4arelay sshd[10845]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown 
Mar 25 16:55:45 f4arelay sshd[10845]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=115.29.194.97 
Mar 25 16:55:47 f4arelay sshd[10845]: Failed password for invalid user vnc from 115.29.194.97 port 56011 ssh2 
Mar 25 16:55:47 f4arelay sshd[10845]: Received disconnect from 115.29.194.97: 11: Bye Bye [preauth] 
Mar 25 16:56:38 f4arelay sshd[10849]: Accepted password for root from 37.134.155.106 port 62645 ssh2 
Mar 25 16:56:38 f4arelay sshd[10849]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0) 
Mar 25 16:56:38 f4arelay sshd[10849]: pam_env(sshd:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory 
Mar 25 16:57:23 f4arelay sudo: root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/less /var/log/auth.log 
Mar 25 16:57:23 f4arelay sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=0) 
Mar 25 16:58:48 f4arelay sshd[10900]: Invalid user test from 115.29.194.97 
Mar 25 16:58:48 f4arelay sshd[10900]: input_userauth_request: invalid user test [preauth] 
Mar 25 16:58:48 f4arelay sshd[10900]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown 
Mar 25 16:58:48 f4arelay sshd[10900]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=115.29.194.97 
Mar 25 16:58:50 f4arelay sshd[10900]: Failed password for invalid user test from 115.29.194.97 port 48110 ssh2 
Mar 25 16:58:50 f4arelay sshd[10900]: Received disconnect from 115.29.194.97: 11: Bye Bye [preauth] 
Mar 25 16:59:48 f4arelay sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root 
Mar 25 17:00:12 f4arelay sudo: root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/less /var/log/auth.log 
Mar 25 17:00:12 f4arelay sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=0)
```

As you can see there is one bot trying to connect continously my server.

I would like to know how to protect it from people like him, I know that is not possible to stop all of that people I just want to make sure that they wont get logged into my server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Use [key-based authentication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server) for SSH instead of password authentication
2. [Change your SSHd port](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/changing-the-ssh-port/) to something other than 22 . This is security through obscurity but is probably justifiable in this case.
3. [fail2ban](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04) users that try to connect on port 22 or try password authentication